# Items not being pushed into the array in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have tree files en.txt, es.txt, and html.txt. I want to use the lines in the first file as patterns and the lines of the second file as replacements. The text that has to be replaced is in the third file (the HTML version of en.text).

The lines in en.txt and es.txt look like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

`esStrings` and `esStrings` are `en.text` and `es.txt` split into arrays (split on new line).

(html.txt is the same but with p tags surrounding the text)

This is the code:

```
fs.readFile('html.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  var result = []

  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }

  for (i = 0; i < enStrings.length; i++) { 
    console.log(enStrings[i])
    var re = new RegExp(enStrings[i], "g")
    for (i = 0; i < esStrings.length; i++) { 
      result = result.push(data.replace(re, esStrings[i]))
    }
  }

  console.log(result)
})
```

If I do `console.log(enStrings[i])`my terminal returns Line 2 indefinitely. If I do console.log(result) the script runs forever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing assignment line when pushing the new item to just using the push function. Also adding semi-colons at the end of your statements will help ensure there are no errors from statements crossing over each other.

Comment: You are using the variable "i"-two times. Try changing it to for example "x" and "y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your nested `for` loops using the same iterator variable `i`.

Also, don't assign `result = result.push(...`.  Just perform the `result.push(`.  It adds to the array already.

Answer (score 2):

Just not assign any value to result in for loop while you push data into array, replace following code of for loop with yours and try again :-

```
for (i = 0; i < esStrings.length; i++) { 
    result.push(data.replace(re, esStrings[i]));
}
```

It may help you.